# How to change button attribute by state parameter - React-Native

Tags: button, react-native, native-base

I am using native-base theme. I want to change button theme by state parameter. 
In code below, what i want to do is when button clicked, button is turning to success button style.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Platform,  StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';    
import { Button, Text} from 'native-base';

class GameScreen extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          answerBtnClr: 'warning'
        }
      }
    changeButton(){
        this.setState({answerBtnClr: 'success'});
    }
 render() {
    return (
     <Button {this.state.answerBtnClr} onPress={() => this.changeButton()}>
       <Text> Change Me </Text>
     </Button>
     )
    }
 }

    export default GameScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
render() {
    const showSuccess = this.state.answerBtn === 'success';
    return (
        <Button success={showSuccess} warning={!showSuccess} ... >
            ...
        </Button>
    )
}
```

**EDIT**
Your state and setState has two different variables but I assume they are the same and that it is just a typo.

Comment: Thanks. It is my question answer. Also I have edited state paramater.